# Product of Determinants in n-form definition

Tags: multilinear-algebra

Watching Frederich Shullers "Lectures on the Geometric Anatomy of Physics" series, he defines the determinant of an Endomorphism $\phi$ as

$$\det \phi = \frac{w(\phi(e_1),\ldots \phi(e_n))}{w(e_1, \ldots e_n)}$$

where $w$ is the volume form on some n dim vector space V

I've been trying to prove the property that $$\det(\phi \odot \psi) = \det(\phi)\det(\psi)$$ but have had trouble doing so via this definition. It seems the anti-symmetry of $w$ is key, but I can't figure out how to work it in.

Comment: As it is written, your expression isn't correct. You should write it as shown in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131414/305862

Comment: See the interesting/didactic notes of Keith Conrad [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf)

Comment: The notes have a derivation using wedge products. Is there some kind of derivation that directly uses the definition I wrote above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can avoid wedge products. But the issue is elsewhere.

The author of the video sweeps some dust under the carpet.

The definition given of the determinant of an endomorphism $\phi$ is in fact the consequence of the following result:

$$\text{for any independent system} \  v_1 \cdots v_n, \ \frac{\det(\phi(v_1), \cdots \phi(v_n))}{\det(v_1 \cdots v_n)} \ \text{is a constant}$$

and to this constant, we give the name $\det(\phi)$. $\square$

The first issue is therefore to be able to establish this result...

Then, we get almost immediately:

$$\underbrace{\frac{\det(\psi \circ \phi(v_1), \cdots \psi \circ \phi(v_n))}{\det(v_1 \cdots v_n)}}_{\det(\psi \circ \phi)}=\underbrace{\frac{\det(\psi \circ \phi(v_1), \cdots \psi \circ \phi(v_n))}{\det(\phi(v_1), \cdots \phi(v_n))}}_{\det(\psi)}\underbrace{\frac{\det(\phi(v_1), \cdots \phi(v_n))}{\det(v_1 \cdots v_n)}}_{\det(\phi)}$$

Comment: I see, so first it would have to be proven that $det(\phi)$ is the same for any set of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$? I think thats possible, you would have to expand $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ in an some separate, arbitrary basis, and then with some rearranging the constants from the numerator and denominator would cancel out

Comment: Yes, I have added to my answer this cancellation.